# NoActiveAccessToken even though Token Exists - OAuth2 + Lumen of Laravel + Swift

Tags: php, swift, laravel, oauth-2.0, lumen

I accessed to the access_token successfully, however I'm having problem getting the user_id. I am getting error:

> `NoActiveAccessTokenException Authorizer.php line 104 Tried to access session data without an active access token`

What am I doing wrong?

```
$app->get('/me', function () {
    $id = Authorizer::getResourceOwnerId();
    return response()->json(['id' => $id]);
});
```

On Swift (note that `token` is valid):

```
func me(handler: (data: NSDictionary?, error: String?) -> Void)
    {
        let url = NSURL(string: "/me", relativeToURL: self.baseUrl)
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

        if let t = self.getAccessToken()
        {
            request.setValue("Bearer \(t)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

            print(t) // Token is valid "y7bPb1NgUBxmHSIbwsgBgPxJcM0ywnithG5PvEEv"

            let taskInstance = DataTaskHandler()
            taskInstance.make(request, handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
                if let res = result
                {
                    if let jsonDictionary = JSONParser(data: res).dictionary()
                    {
                            print(jsonDictionary)
                        handler(data: jsonDictionary, error: nil)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        else
        {
            handler(data:nil, error: "The access token is not available")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take into account that you access_token is only valid for shor time. SO after that time, the access token must be refreshed, using the refresh_toke, grant_type. Check here the details: https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/wiki/Implementing-an-Authorization-Server-with-the-Refresh-Token-Grant

Alternatively you can increase the time for the access_token. Just go to config/oauth.php and change the ttl index (normally is 3600 -> 1 hour), please take into account that one access_token must have shor time for security reasons, so dot increase too much the ttl.

---

EDIT:

It is importan to check that you are using the oauth middleware in the controller method or during the request, because this middleware stablish the access_token value during the whole request.
Just add this in the constructor of your controller.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('oauth');
}
```

Hope it helps.

Bets wishes.

PS (for other readers): This question is related with the Lumen course [here](https://www.udemy.com/lumen-restful-api-and-homestead-for-lumen-by-laravel-and-php/?couponCode=forum)

Comment: For testing, I increased the access_token. Also, I'm trying the `app.dev/me` as soon as I login, so as soon as token is created. I am stuck so badly. I may be out of the path completely(!) but; maybe it's because of `request.setValue("Bearer \(t)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")` this line and maybe I am posting a wrong value. I tried to use `(Request $request)` to check but I think it doesn't work in Lumen. Or as I said, maybe I'm completely out of scope

Comment: Are you sending an access_token in that request? It is neccessary to send an access_token in the request to obtain the owner.